# 2FA codes not received on Messages in macOS

Tags: macos, messages, sms

I use Messages on macOS (both Catalina and now Big Sur) with iCloud syncing on.

I can receive and send messages from/on macOS. Except for 2FA (two-factor authentication) codes. These codes, from any service I've used, only arrive on my iPhone, and not on any of the Mac computers I'm logged in with iCloud.

I haven't figured out a way to fix this issue. 2FA codes used to work a while ago (I used the auto-completion feature when login into Twitter or GitHub from Safari on macOS), but at some point they stopped coming in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you are receiving/sending iMessages on your Mac, but not SMS (used for 2FA).

In your iPhone settings, go to “Messages”, and setup “Text Message Forwarding” to your Mac.

More info on [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208386).

Comment: OMG, that was so obvious, didn't think of that setting at all. Thank you!

Comment: Just got a new computer and didn't think about how I would need to do this again. Thanks!