# Apple Watch doesn't notify me of SMS messages

Tags: notifications, apple-watch, sms

Whenever I get an SMS message from someone not in my contacts, my watch does not vibrate. I have my watch set to Mirror my iPhone's messages settings, and switching it to custom doesn't change anything. It doesn't matter if the sender is in my contacts or not (though I do have the "filter unknown senders" setting off).

This has been going on for a while, but I've gotten tired of having to manually pull up 2FA codes every time I need to login somewhere, since I can't just look down and my wrist and see the message pop up.

I've since unpaired and restored my watch (updating it), still experiencing the issue.

Comment: Sounds like you're having issues specifically with SMS, not iMessage. Does Apple Watch require [text message forwarding](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208386) to be set up? Also I'm curious why you need to read your 2FA from your watch instead of the device you need to enter it on - do you use non apple devices? [Possibly related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394792/151404).

Comment: @JBallin, text messaging forwarding does not need to be setup for Apple Watches, the message even shows up in the Messages app, there's just no notification. My most common interaction with 2FA happens when I'm logging in on a computer, not my phone, so it can't auto populate.

Comment: Why don't you have text messaging set up on your computer?

Comment: @JBallin because it is a Windows PC...